# Error when I try to uncheck all DataGridViewCheckBoxCell in a gridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to uncheck all the checkboxes in a specific gridview column in my winforms app when I click on a button:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            (gridview.Rows[i].Cells[4] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = false;
        }
    }
```

When I execute my code, it uncheck only the first one and it throws this exception :

> Row provided does not belong to this DataGridView control. Parameter
>   name: dataGridViewRow

I tried with this code but I have get the same error :

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridview.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
        {
            (row.Cells[4] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = false;
        }
```

I changed the columnindex by his name but I still have the same error :

```
            (row.Cells["gvcField"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = false;
```

I tried also to use this instruction because the gridview is not readonly :

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

but nothing changes.

I forget to talk about two small details :

1. This is not a winform application, It's a .NET plugin (an assembly that we load in an existing winform application to add new features).
2. I'm using 4 gridviews in my plugin in the same screen.

Did someone has another idea to share with me about this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: `i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1` doesn't work.

Comment: Why did you talk about `NewRow` I don't create a new rows, I just try to uncheck all checkboxes in a Datagridviewcolumn.